# App start it's previous state WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

How to run a app from it previous state if app exist in memory WP8 like as Dailymotion App. And  app which doesn't start from start screen even if it is running but not on foregound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WP8 this is called Fast App Resume.
You can implement it using following guideline: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj735579(v=vs.105).aspx